# Main page change through Mediawiki:Mainpage url doesn't work on Mediawiki 1.22

Tags: mediawiki

I've installed mediawiki 1.22.5 and I've tried to change the main page through the Mediawiki:Mainpage url to another page but It doesn't seem to work! 
What I do is edit the http://www.mysite.com/en/index.php?title=MediaWiki:MainPage and write in the text window the name of the page I want as the main page (I've even copied/pasted it to make sure it is written correctly!). However when I click on the logo it takes me to the default main page, not the one I wrote in Mediawiki:Mainpage.
I can change the main page link in the side-bar but the problem with the logo remains.

And I don't want to create just a redirect as it is not elegant on the main page.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaWiki:MainPage` should change also the target of the logo link. If it doesn't, my first guess would be extensive caching.

Is your wiki public? Can you provide us with an url?

Comment: Yeah... should have cleared the cache... Stupid me! :p Now it works! Thanks!